# Debugging #Value! on VBA

Tags: vba

When I run TEST() in the following VBA code, the result shows as belows
[image: RESULT OF TEST()]

But if I run LASTEST_DATE(..) in Excel Sheet, It shows #VALUE! error.

Could you any one knows why?
[image: RESULT IN EXCEL SHEET]

```
Public Function LASTEST_DATE(arg1 As String, arg2 As String) As Date
    Set aSheet = Worksheets("L4 CSU Schedule Excel Dump")
    Dim lastestDate As Date

    With aSheet.Range("A2:AA5000")
        Set System = .Find(What:=arg1, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not System Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = System.Address

            Do
                If (aSheet.Range("AA" & System.Row) > lastestDate) Then
                    lastestDate = aSheet.Range("AA" & System.Row).Value
                End If

                Set System = .FindNext(System)
            Loop While Not System Is Nothing And System.Address <> firstAddress
        End If

    End With

    LASTEST_DATE = lastestDate
End Function

Public Sub TEST()
    Debug.Print (LASTEST_DATE(3100100, "System Commissioned"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As VBA doesn't have short-circuit evaluation the right expression of this

```
Loop While Not System Is Nothing And System.Address <> firstAddress
```

fails when System is nothing.

You could try something like this:

```vb
Do
    (...)
    Select Case True
        Case (System Is Nothing), System.Address = firstAddress
            endLoop = False
        Case Else
            endLoop = True
        End Select
Loop While endLoop
```